# Python - Getting textboxes input data by Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

lastly I'm working about a Python project which uses the library "selenium". The project should type in passwords according to the usernames that it has got.  My problem is that I don't know how to get data from a text box.
For example, if I want to use the project on "Facebook", at first I have to get the E-mail which the user typed in (kind of like putting it as a string variable), and then I have to type in the correct password (I know how to do that). My main problem is that the command " .text " doesn't work because the E-mail isn't found in any attribute of the textbox, so I can't call it.
Does someone have a solution please?

The current lines are :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\User\Desktop\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/stype=lo&jlou=AfdFutu6bihEQajPctMRwj2ySoaIGAE71YZ0aBZe9FYV4Xd2XuZ3SGth5wernWcF7s4pSvZH5W6f0ed2BfafHrkbupDcW4GDQECBTnhQID1FQ&smuh=4370&lh=Ac_eTqeC_DcDMq9f')
mail = driver.find_element_by_id('email').text
```

The problem is that the current "mail" variable is an empty string, because the E-mail textbox of Facebook's website is empty as it's waiting for the client to type in his E-mail. I'm trying to get the client's E-mail AFTER he typed it in.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, please supply what code you currently have.

Comment: driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\User\Desktop\chromedriver.exe')            driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/?stype=lo&jlou=AfdFutu6bihEQajPctMRwj2ySoaIGAE71YZ0aBZe9FYV4Xd2XuZ3SGth5wernWcF7-s4pSvZH5W6f0ed2BfafHrkbupDcW4GDQECBTnhQID1FQ&smuh=4370&lh=Ac_eTqeC_DcDMq9f')                                                                       mail = driver.find_element_by_id('email').text

Answer (score 2):

You can get value from `input` field simply as

```
email_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="email"]')
print(email_input.get_attribute('value'))
```

**Update**

If you want to get text from `input` after user enter email:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\User\Desktop\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/stype=lo&jlou=AfdFutu6bihEQajPctMRwj2ySoaIGAE71YZ0aBZe9FYV4Xd2XuZ3SGth5wernWcF7s4pSvZH5W6f0ed2BfafHrkbupDcW4GDQECBTnhQID1FQ&smuh=4370&lh=Ac_eTqeC_DcDMq9f')
email = input("Please enter your Email: ")
email_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="email"]')
email_input.send_keys(email)
print(email_input.get_attribute('value')) # or just print(email)
```

Note, that user should enter `email` value to command line, but not to browser input field

Comment: `<input type="email" class="inputtext" name="email" id="email" value="" tabindex="1">` That's how it looks. Why do you think that there is no `value` attribute?

Comment: Your'e right, I just didn't see the "value" there. Anyway, about your code, it works well, but the problem is that it prints the email_input before I even finish typing in my E-mail... Do you an idea to make it wait untill I finish my E-mail?

Comment: Do you want to input `email` value manually and then get value from field?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want to be able to get the E-mail right after the client typed it in.

Comment: Checked that, but I need the website to work as it usually does.  The user should see his E-mail typed in the textbox by the time he is typing it. Your code will show him his mail in the textbox, only after he finishes typing the whole E-mail.

Comment: This is much more complicated as there is no explicit way to define the moment when user finish entering characters... You should implement nice piece of `JavaScript` injection to perform that...